# Maltego transform not creating/linking all entities

Tags: python, data-science

I am creating a maltego transform in Python that will be creating a lot of entities. I am running into an issue where the transform is not adding all of the entities to the graph. I am using the paid version of maltego, so that is not the issue.

For example, if I have the following code:

```
def create_entities(cls, request, response):
     response.addEntity(Domain, "1")
     response.addEntity(Domain, "2")
     #Numbers 3 through 12...
     response.addEntity(Domain, "13")
```

When I run the transform, only 12 entities are created and linked. I need to run the transform again to get the 13th entity. The entity that is skipped changes each time. If I get rid of one of the lines and have only 12, it works as expected.

I know that there is a 12 entity limit on the free version, but as I said, I am using the paid one.

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I am assuming it is a problem with maltego and not my code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. You have to change the "number of results" slider in the Investigate tab to more than 12.